# Ruby class to symbol

Tags: ruby

I would like to get an object's class and turn it into a symbol. In particular, given this:

```
class Apple
end

class Apple_Pie
  def name
    "apple pies"
  end
end

fruit_table = {:Apple => :Apple_Pie}

a = Apple.new
```

I would like to get an instance of the class `Apple_Pie` starting from `a`. I tried:

```
obj = Object.const_get(fruit_table[a.class])
obj.name
```

expecting

```
apple pies
```

but this doesn't actually happen. I am not sure how to turn the class into a symbol. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `Module#name` to get the string name of the class, then cast it to a symbol using `String#to_sym`.

From my console:

```
> a.class
=> Apple
> a.class.name
=> "Apple"
> a.class.name.to_sym
=> :Apple
```

Comment: ah, the name of the class. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just pasted your code, and add **.new** to `obj =  obj = Object.const_get(fruit_table[a.class.name.to_sym]).new.name
It worked.
Not sure if this is actually what you wanted though.

update: forgot to add **.name.to_sym**

Comment: It's interesting that worked. The issue I was having is that the class is not actually a key in the hash, so trying to hash on the class itself would return nil.

Comment: That was the OPs mistake besides the point mentioned in the question.

Comment: updated answer: I've used class.name.to_sym to get the class name from Hash

Answer (score 0):

```
    ob_demoobject=Hash.new
    sym=ob_demoobject.class.to_s.to_sym
```